# Looking for inline html editor

Tags: javascript, text-editor

I'm looking for a simple javascript html editor that support:

- using div(contenteditable) insteal of using iframe
- auto resize content height when typing.
- support some functions: bold, italic, orderedlist..., could plugin more toolbar button in the furture.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think NicEdit meets all your requirements... no iframe, simple and lightweight, simple text formatting and lists, expands as you type, plus a lot of the other usual stuff you'd expect from a wysiwyg editor.

http://nicedit.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can check this one

http://xreader.github.com/inplaceeditor/ it uses contenteditable

Demo can be found here http://xreader.github.com/inplaceeditor/demo.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the HTML editors supported by major CMSen.  For example, Joomla! has pluggable inline HTML editors.  Take your pick and use one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it uses iframe or not but check out CKEditor

http://ckeditor.com/demo